# Could i search between keys of a hash and assign its value to a variable in Perl?

Tags: perl, search, hash, pattern-matching, substr

I want to use substr function to recuperate some nucleotides in a sequences. Here i have the FASTA format of those sequences:

```
>dvex28051
AAAACAAAAACATTCGCTAGAAAGTAATCAGCTGGTCATTTATTTGAAATGTTAATGATATATTTCATGTTGCTAATTTTTTATGAAAAAAATCATTGCTTATTTAATTACTCTTGGTTCTTGACCAACTATAAAAGCATTGTTTAGTATCAAGTGTCCAGGTATCAGCAGTTTTGTTTGAAAACAAACTTTTATTCATGCAGTCAGTGGCGGATCCAGGTAGAGTGCAGAGGCAGCACCCTCCGTCAGAAAACCAAAAAAAGAAGAAATGAAAAATTATAAAAAAAATTTCTAAACGTTGGTGCACTTAAGTGTAGCAAAAAATTCCTGTTTAGATATTCAGTGGGGAGCGACACCTTTTGGGGCCTATAGCTTCAAATCTTACTTGGTGACCTAAAATCGCTTTTTCGTTGGATCTGCGAAAGCTAGAATTTGGTTGCTGCAAATCGAATCGGTGCATCAACTGCATCAATATCAACGATGTGGTGACTGGTGGTATATTTTGGGTTCGTGCAATGCTACATTTATTTCAATCATATTTCAAGGCAGAAAGGGAAAGAAAACATCAGGTCAAGACAGTGGCGTAGCGAGGGAAGGGGGGCATACGTCCCCGGGCGCAACACGATGTCTTTTTTTTTAATCATCTGCGAAATTCAGACATTTTTTAGAGACTAAATGAAACTATGGAAAACCGGGCCCTTATAAAAGTTGAGACCAAGTGAAAAACTGGGGATAAAACATGAAAATCGGGCTCCAAAAGAATGAGAGTCCGCCCTTGGTCTGTACCAGCATGATTTGAGCGCAAATTTCATTAAGCCCCCGGGCGCAAGACACTCACGCTACGCCCCTGGGTAAAGACAAACAGAGTAGTTTTTCTTATAAACACAAGCATGCACAAACAACATAAAAACAAAACACAGTTTTTTTTAAGACGATGTGCTGCGTGCACCCGCTCAATGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTATAGAAAAGCAAAACTTTGAAAGGTTAACGTCAACTCATTTTACAACAATTTGTGGCAAATGGTATCAAGGTATCAAGCAATTAACTAAATGTCTTCCACTAGAACGCAGAACACCATTTTGCAATTATTTATTTGATGTAAACCAGTGTGTTAGATCAAAATCACTTCGACGCCGTTTTTTGACTCCGTGAAAATCTTGGTATTCTTCTCGCATTGCATAATGATGGTTTGTTGAAATAAAATTAAACGCTTAACGTTCTTAAAATGAGCGCGATACTACTTTTCTTTGTAGATTTTCTGCATGCGCTCCTTTTAAGTTGATCCCGAGCTACAAACTTCTTTATGAACGTTTTGGATTTCTCCAAAATAAAGCCTGCAAGCAGTTTTCTAAAAACACCGCACCCCCCATTAGGAATTTCTAGATCCGCCCCTGCATACAGTATTTGTTAATTATTAAAACCAACCAGCAGCAATTGTTTATTCAATGACTATTAAACCAACCTGGATAGTGCGTTTGGTCTTGATTGAAGCGATTGCTGCATTGACGTCTTTCGGAACCACATCACC
>dvex294195
GAATCAGTGGAAAAGTCACAACGCAGCTTGCCGAATTACTGCAGATTCTTTACACTTTTTTTTCTACATTATCACTGTTTTGCTTAATTTTCAATTATAGAAATCAAAATTAATAACTGGTATGTAGTTGGTCGGTGCTTCGAGAAAGTAGCCTACTCAATGATTTCTCAGAATGTTACAGTACTTCAAAAAAACAGACTACCCATTTCAAAAAATATAAACCTAGTA
```

I want to compare each keys of the hash with the Hit column (dvex\d++) of this table:

```
#Query Hit  sense start end star_q end_q lenght_q # this line is informative don't make part of the code.
miRNA1 dvex28051 +  205     232     11  38  51
miRNA1 dvex202016 -  75    106  17  48  51
miRNA1 dvex294195 +  55     85     11  48  51
```

If this exist, I want to assign its value of the hash to a variable (i.e: $sequence) for apply a substr function:
`my $fragment = substr $sequence, $start, $length_sequence;`

I make an array with the sequences, and tried to reading it each 2 values and compare it:

```
while (my $line1 = <$MYINPUTFILE>){ #Entry of the sequences Fasta file
chomp $line1;
push @array_lines, $line1;
}
while (my $line2 = <$IN>){ #Entry of the table
chomp $line2;
push @database_lines, $line2;
}   
foreach my $database_line (@database_lines){ #each value of the table
my @entry = split /\s++/,$database_line;
$pattern = $entry[1];
$query = $entry[0];
$start = $entry[3];
$l_pattern = length $pattern;
$end = $entry[4];
$lng_sequence = ($end - $start) + 1;
$sense = $entry[2];
$l_query = $entry[7];

my $count = 2;
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#array_lines; $i +=$count){
    chomp $array_lines[$i-2];
    chomp $array_lines[$i-1];   
    $seq = $array_lines[$i-1];
    $header = $array_lines[$i-2];
if($new_header =~ /$pattern/ && $l_header == $l_pattern){
    if(($end+$right_diff+$increment) > $l_query){
        $clean_seq = substr $seq, $start, $l_query;
} else {;} 
}
```

The problem with my code is that Perl recognizes $seq as the last one Sequence. And always apply substr function on this $seq. I need to search the $pattern and search in those sequences, if exist, assign $seq to its sequence, next apply substr function. 
Some suggestions?

Comment: You're asking us to write the whole program. Disenfranchise it from your task at hand and questions about perl.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot it! I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two significant problems with your code.  First, in the loop:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#array_lines; $i +=$count){
    chomp $array_lines[$i-2];
    chomp $array_lines[$i-1];   
    $seq = $array_lines[$i-1];
```

`$i` is set to zero the first time through, but you access array elements `$i-1` and `$i-2`.  Element `-1` will be the last element of the array, and `-2` will be the second to the last element.  So it looks like `$seq` and `$header` will have incorrect values the first time through your loop.  Maybe you need to start `$i` at `$count` instead of zero?

Secondly, in this line:

```
if(($end+$right_diff+$increment) > $l_query){
```

`$increment` appears only here in your code.  It is never set to anything.  Did you mean to use `$i` here?

*A few other suggestions:*

Make sure you `use warnings; use strict;` This will catch errors such as the `$increment` variable above.

Here is a simpler way to read a file into an array:

```
my @array_lines = <$MYINPUTFILE>;
chomp @array_lines;
```

Within regexes, `++` is a special quantifier that disables backtracking.  If you want to split on one or more whitespace characters, it is more typical to use `split /\s+/`, or the equivalent `split ' '`

With this line, you appear to be simply checking that two strings are equal:

```
if($new_header =~ /$pattern/ && $l_header == $l_pattern)
```

You could just do this instead:

```
if($new_header eq $pattern)
```

When you have multiple conditions, it is clearer to put them all in one `if` statement instead of using nested statements.  If you have many conditions, you can put them on multiple lines for clarity.

It isn't necessary to use `else {;}`  If you don't need to do anything there, just omit the `else` clause altogether.